# Issue in routing in existing ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, iis-express

I have a problem with routing in an existing ASP.NET application for work. I have the code for the application and i can build and run it. When i run it I see the home page, but all links and images have invalid URL's. For each URL the same problem occurs.

For example an image on the home page has this src:
 src="/appName/Images/img.jpg".
but the image is actually at "/Images/img.jpg". Notice the missing '/appName', this is the problem with every link / image.

The root folder of the application is in the folder '/appName', but the URL's/images seem to think it is one folder above that.

Now I could change every URL and take out the '/appName', but I feel like it should be possible to run the website correctly without changing the code. Maybe i should change something about the environment or IIS express.

HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") returns the path to the /appName folder. So the img src and a href start looking in /appName/appName which doesn't exist.

I have searched online, but cannot find anything.
I've already tried changing the root URL in applicationhost.config, but this resulted in IIS not finding an application in that folder.

I know the website works in the production environment, though i currently have no access to the production environment. But i do think it is an environmental setting (maybe in IIS).

So does anybody have an idea how to change it so the links think the root URL is one folder above the actual root folder in IIS?

Comment: how or wheredo you access images? could you provide some code? it might be different if you want to access it from css, cshtml or some custom file controller/provider

Comment: @Pribina what do you mean by access exactly? One of the images is defined like this <img src="/appName/Images/img.jpg" />. Typing "localhost:7037/appName/Images/img.jpg" into the address bar results in a 404. Typing "localhost:7037/Images/img.jpg" shows me the image.

Comment: okay, could you show us your cshtml code?

Comment: I'd rather not show too much code, since it is a project for a customer. The problem only occurs with <img src and <a href links, so i don't believe any other html code could help you help me. Note: this is not a Core application, just regular ASP.NET. I have .aspx and .aspx.cs files, no .cshtml.

Comment: i understand you dont want to show production code. I wanted to see how you provide links inside of aspx file ex. static text "/appName/Images/img.jpg" or with tilde symbol "~/appName/Images/img.jpg"

Comment: No tilde symbol are used. The src's and href's start with /appName/.

Comment: I am currently using a hotfix (find and replace every instance of /appName/ with /). But I am uncertain if this will be compatible with the production environment.